# Explicitly specifying static dictionary value types, while inferring exact shape (or at least keys)

Tags: typescript, dictionary

I want to create a **static** dictionary, as a single object literal, for which I would

1. explicitly specify the type of values, so I get typechecks and IDE suggestions
2. still be able to infer the exact shape (or at least keys)

I know I can achieve the first part in vacuum by simply typing the dict:

```js
type Item = { id: number, description: string }
const staticDict: Partial<Record<string, Item>> = {
  first: { id: 1, description: "first" },
  second: { id: 2, description: "second" },
}
```

and the second part via `as const` assertion:

```js
type Item = { id: number, description: string }
const StaticDict = {
  first: { id: 1, description: "first" },
  second: { id: 2, description: "second" },
} as const
```

but how do I combine the approaches, while still retaining the dictionary definition as a single literal (without declaring and typing `first` and `second` in advance)?

This doesn't really work:

```js
type Item = { id: number, description: string }
const staticDict: Partial<Record<string, Item>> = {
  first: { id: 1, description: "first" },
  second: { id: 2, description: "second" }, 
} as const
type Keys = keyof typeof StaticDict // results in `string`, I want "first" | "second"
```

And I don't want to assert each item `as Item`, since that approach doesn't stop me from specifying unknown properties. Are there any other options left for me?

Answer (score 1):

A workaround to get at least type-checking is not to broaden the type `staticDict` but to later assign it to the broader type to check its shape is correct. You can do this as a const in a block which is by definition not visible beyond the single line. This might make its intent clearer (e.g. it's a check and not used anywhere else).

There may be a nicer syntactic sugar for your case (e.g. if there are lots of them, assign them to a typed array).

```
type Item = { id: number, description: string }
const staticDict = {
  first: { id: 1, description: "first" },
  second: { id: 2, description: "second" },
  third: "incorrect"
} as const;
{
    //correctly reports error
    const checkDict: Partial<Record<string, Item>> = staticDict;
}
//correctly infers keys
type Keys = keyof typeof staticDict;
```

Comment: Interesting idea! I find this potentially useful as an additional check, but it doesn't guard against adding unknown properties on `Item`. At which point it seems I'm better of asserting every item `as Item` - that way I also get IDE suggestions inside the item objects.

Comment: Oh, but the assertions I described broaden the type, while your approach doesn't ... Now I get it :)