# Use typescript type in generated javascript

Tags: typescript

So I'm stuck on a (confusing for me) situation, any help would be greatly appreciated:

I have some big objects with different types of properties.  I'm using generics and iterating through the fields to render inputs based on the field's type.  Ex text field for string, checkbox for bool, and so on.

Some of the fields could be null, so I can't just use typeof on the actual value, which means I have to create a type schema for the JS, which is feeling super redundant and not very DRY, just to create the inputs ex:

```
interface Data {
  foo: string
  bar: number
  baz: Date
}

const dataTypes = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: "number",
  baz: "Date"
}
```

It's a long shot, but I guess my question is: can I use the Typescript type in the JavaScript logic?  Ex:

```
if ( typescript-typeof val == "boolean | null" ) drawCheckbox()
```

Thank you for any help!

=== EDIT ===
Example of when JS doesn't know the type:

```
interface Obj {
  foo: string | null
  bar: number | null
  baz: Date | null
}

const obj: Obj = {
  foo: "abc",
  bar: null,
  baz: new Date()
}

function drawInput(val: Obj[keyof Obj]) {
  switch (typeof val) {
    case "string": drawTextField()
    case "boolean": drawCheckbox()
    case "object": // originally a string, boolean, or Date?
  }
}
```

=== EDIT #2 only way I know how to make it work--- with redundant code ===

```
interface Obj {
  foo: string | null,
  bar: boolean | null,
  baz: Date | null
}

const objTypes: {[key in keyof Obj]: string} = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: "boolean",
  baz: "Date"
}

const obj: Obj = {
  foo: "abc",
  bar: null,
  baz: new Date()
}

function drawInput <K extends keyof Obj>(key: K, val: Obj[K]) {
  switch (objTypes[key]) {
    case "string": drawTextField(val)
    case "boolean": drawCheckbox(val)
    case "Date": drawDatePicker(val)
    case "object": // will never happen now
  }
}
```

Comment: `typeof value === 'boolean' || value === null`? What's so special about the *Typescript* type? And no, they only exist at compile time.

Comment: You can use typeof in javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this pattern address your case?

It ensures you only assign names to types in one place, but allows them to drive javascript AND typescript logic in the ways you've requested.

```
type Form = Readonly<{
  [k in string]:"string"|"number"|"Date"
}>

type ValidationType<F extends Form> = Partial<{
  [K in keyof F]: F[K] extends "string"? string : F[K] extends "number" ? number : F[K] extends "Date" ? Date : never
}>

//DRY happens here
const myForm = {
  foo: "string",
  bar: "number",
  baz: "Date"
} as const;

//autocompletion happens here
const myRecord:ValidationType<typeof myForm> = {

}

function renderControls<F extends Form>(form:F, record:ValidationType<F>){
  for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(form)){
    if(form[key] === "string") { 
      renderString(record, key);
    }
    if(form[key] === "Date") {
      renderDate(record, key);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow holy cow you got a JS object to behave like a TS interface!  This is excellent.  It's unconventional but exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you for your help, I wish I could upvote it more than once.

Comment: The only sad thing is that myForm cannot be typed like `const myform:Form` as that broadens the type which will otherwise be inferred by typescript. There's a workaround like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67366450/explicitly-specifying-static-dictionary-value-types-while-inferring-exact-shape/67367613#67367613 if you want the compiler to tell you that you put e.g. "date" instead of "Date"

Comment: Actually as long as it's passed into renderControls you'd get a compiler error anyway as it would choke and tell you it's not a Form.

Answer (score 2):

The `typeof` keyword isn't specific to TypeScript. You can use it in JavaScript just as well.

Note: if `val` is `null`, `typeof val` will return "object".

```js
if (typeof val === "boolean") drawCheckbox()
```

You can't however make types in JavaScript, like you would in TypeScript.

Comment: Hi MrCoding thanks for responding.  I guess I'm still misunderstanding, how does JavaScript know if a null object property is supposed to be a string or a boolean?  I'll try to add an example

Comment: You can actually use typeof on the variable even if it is null. It will just not return `boolean` for example but rather `object`. So it doesn't really know that, but that's why you're checking for null as well

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but If I use typeof on the value, and it returns null, I won't know what type of input to render

Comment: typeof will never return null. It might return object when value is null

Comment: Just now I got what you are trying to do, and I have a disappointing answer. It's no possible with JS as long as you already have an object with all the values assigned to it

Comment: You could initialize the object with some placeholder values. So you could use a class instead of interfaces.

Comment: Oof bummer.  I guess that answers that question, thanks for being patient and explaining it to me.  The placeholder values might work, I'll try that out.

Comment: Just commenting for those in this thread who felt there was no solution. The solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67551020/use-typescript-type-in-generated-javascript/67552924#67552924 uses an `as const` trick to make a Form structure which acts as both a javascript object (for runtime logic to e.g. render the Form) while also driving typescript types (for validation and autocompletion of validated objects to 'match' the Form).